# Boolean logic in Pandas is returning "KeyError: True"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to use a select statement to drop all rows from a dateframe where the values in a certain column don't begin with 126.1.

An example of my data set is:

```
File      Date          Time         RA         Dec
ad0147.fits  18-02-13  22:26:01.779  126.109510  27.360011
ad0147.fits  18-02-13  22:26:01.779  126.061077  27.361124
ad0147.fits  18-02-13  22:26:01.779  125.994430  27.363504
```

I want to filter out all RA values that do not begin with 126.1.

I used this:

```
data2 = data2.drop(data2[str(data2['RA'])[0:5] is not str(126.1)].index)
```

where data2 is my dataframe.

It is returning the error "KeyError: True".

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you think `str(data2['RA'])[0:5] is not str(126.1)` is doing? You should try breaking it up into individual parts and seeing what it's doing.

Comment: Don't use `is` and `is not` to compare strings, use `==` and `!=`.

Comment: FYI `str(data2['RA'])[0:5]` in your case evaluates to `'0    '`. That converts the slice of the series to a string, which will include the index. It's good practice to break up complicated logic like yours into smaller, more manageable pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the .str method which is available on any Pandas Series (which is what the columns of the data frame are). It supports regular expression syntax. I often search for what I don't want and then negate it with the ~. Like this:

```
df = df[~df.RA.str.contains('126.1')]
```

Comment: OP wants to exclude that rows that start with `126.1`, so `.str.startswith` is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot wrong with:

```
str(data2['RA'])[0:5] is not str(126.1)
```

To begin with, `is not` will evaluate to `True` or `False`, but you are trying to create a *boolean array* for selection, so right off the bat this is misguided. Second, you should *never* use `is` to compare `str` object to begin with. For these sorts of string manipulations on `pandas.Series` objects, there are built-in vectorized methods accessible through `.str` which mimic the built-in string methods. So given:

```
>>> df
          File      Date          Time          RA        Dec
0  ad0147.fits  18-02-13  22:26:01.779  126.109510  27.360011
1  ad0147.fits  18-02-13  22:26:01.779  126.061077  27.361124
2  ad0147.fits  18-02-13  22:26:01.779  125.994430  27.363504
>>> df.dtypes
File     object
Date     object
Time     object
RA      float64
Dec     float64
dtype: object
```

You could use:

```
>>> df.RA.astype(str).str.startswith('126.1')
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: RA, dtype: bool
```

And simply combine that with boolean-indexing:

```
>>> df[df.RA.astype(str).str.startswith('126.1')]
          File      Date          Time         RA        Dec
0  ad0147.fits  18-02-13  22:26:01.779  126.10951  27.360011
```